# docker desktop mongodb コンテナを作り直すとデータベースの作り直しになるのか？

Tags: docker, mongodb

docker desktop でmongodb公式イメージを利用しています。
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=description

```
docker run --name mongodb -v /e/Project/mongodata:/data/db -d -p 0.0.0.0:27017:27017 --net f_network mongo:4.0.3
```

/DATA/DB はホスト側のディレクトリを指定して保存しているのですが、
コンテナを作り直すとコレクションが消えてしまうようです。
ユーザーとデータベース名だけは残っているようです。
コンテナを作り直すとデータベースの作り直しになってしまうのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の手順で確認してみましたが、コマンド自体は問題ないように見えます。

> コンテナを作り直すとデータベースの作り直しになってしまうのでしょうか？

これに対する回答は「いいえ」です。ホスト側のボリュームをマウントしているので永続化層はコンテナの外側にあります。

考えられる原因として推測されるのは、

1. コンテナを再度起動するときにマウントするパスが異なっている
2. 追加したコレクションを消す処理を行なっており、コンテナが削除したタイミングと近いためそれと勘違いした
3. マウントしたホスト側のディレクトリが何らかの理由で削除されている

のいずれかかと思います。一度確認してみることをおすすめします。

### 確認手順

#### 1. mongodbをローカルで構築

```sh
# Desktopに`db-sample`というディレクトリを作成
$ cd ~/Desktop && mkdir -p db-sample && cd db-sample

$ docker run --name mongodb \
              -v $(pwd)/db:/data/db \     # 現在位置のディレクトリをマウント
              -d \
              -p 0.0.0.0:27017:27017 \
              mongo:4.0.3
```

#### 2. ディレクトリを確認

mongodbを構築すると、ローカル(`~/Desktop/db-sample`）に`db`ディレクトリが作成されていることを確認

```sh
$ ls
db
```

#### 3. mongodbに接続

[mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/)を利用してホストから接続します

```sh
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017
```

#### 4. mongodbにデータを追加

```sh
# DBを確認
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB

> use sample

> db.myCollection.insertMany([
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "notebook", qty: 50, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "A" },
   { item: "paper", qty: 100, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "D" },
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, status: "D" },
   { item: "postcard", qty: 45, size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" }
]);
```

#### 5. mongodbのデータを確認

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
sample  0.000GB

> use sample

> db.myCollection.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fa7858911d23499839bb28a"), "x" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fa785c111d23499839bb28b"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "size" : { "h" : 14, "w" : 21, "uom" : "cm" }, "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fa785c111d23499839bb28c"), "item" : "notebook", "qty" : 50, "size" : { "h" : 8.5, "w" : 11, "uom" : "in" }, "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fa785c111d23499839bb28d"), "item" : "paper", "qty" : 100, "size" : { "h" : 8.5, "w" : 11, "uom" : "in" }, "status" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fa785c111d23499839bb28e"), "item" : "planner", "qty" : 75, "size" : { "h" : 22.85, "w" : 30, "uom" : "cm" }, "status" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fa785c111d23499839bb28f"), "item" : "postcard", "qty" : 45, "size" : { "h" : 10, "w" : 15.25, "uom" : "cm" }, "status" : "A" }
```

#### 6. mongodbのコンテナを停止・削除

```
$ docker stop mongodb && docker rm mongodb
```

#### 7. 再起動して確認

1. 手順1 **mongodbをローカルで構築**を実行します。
2. 手順5 **mongodbのデータを確認**を実行します

insertしたデータが存在していることが確認できます。

Comment: 試したところうまくいきました。
どうもdockerでのmongodbの起動にちょっとタイムラグがあったようです。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決した場合、自分の回答を投稿し解決済みにするか、本回答を採用するなどのアクションをとることで他の回答者の回遊を円滑にすることができます。